# How to use http.Get in a TLSClient in Go?

Tags: ssl, go, https, tls1.2

Hi I want to perform a GET Request in GO after creating a tlsclient, for example:

```
client, err := docker.NewTLSClient(sconf.DockConf.Endpoint, sconf.DockConf.Cert, sconf.DockConf.Key, sconf.DockConf.Ca)
```

then how can I perform a Get request in GO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what package you are using but the http package has a *NewRequest* function

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
client.Do(req)
```

--Edit

In addition, here is a full working TLS example with client certificates (I did not create this gist)

https://gist.github.com/michaljemala/d6f4e01c4834bf47a9c4

Comment: great I need something like this but from which library is this client? or in other words how to create it?

Comment: ok you are using the net/http but how can I create a tlsclient in this library given the certificates?